# Android Interface tests for different resolutions

Tags: android, testing, user-interface, resolution

Is there any framework or automated way to test an interface for Android? I mean, I would like to automatically generate a visual test for each interface and resolution, in order to validate it or not, and do it automatically and quickly.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "give the test framework an interface"? You mean a mockup or wireframe against which the actual app can be compared?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I have rewritten the question.

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate then, have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673746/gui-testing-with-instrumentation-in-android

Comment: What do you mean by a visual test? As in you want to watch the test as it's being performed?